# SQL: Missing FROM Clause Entry

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

The following query is intended to list the top rated movie(s) from each year:

```
with

p_names as (select movie_id, name as p_name
from movie_names where primary = true),

--Table of the top rating of each year

m as (select year_released as yr, max(rating) as rating_max from 
p_names natural join movies natural join ratings
group by year_released),

--compilation of all needed tables and columns

t as (select p_name, year_released, rating, votes from 
p_names natural join movies natural join ratings)

--select a row if its year and rating match the "top per year" 
--list kept in m

select p_name, year_released, rating, votes 
from t where t.year_released = m.yr and m.rating = t.rating_max;
```

Upon running it, I get "Missing FROM-clause entry for table m." I've tried to solve this and keep running into examples where the table hasn't been created before the FROM clause is initiated, but as far as I can tell table m has been created before that point. What's gone wrong?

Comment: Dont' use keyword as alias max(rating) as **max**

Comment: Okay, I changed it to rating_max, same error.

Comment: change from t to from t,m

Comment: Ah, that did it! There were a couple of other things to sort out as well but that was the big one, have never actually used selection with commas in that manner, thank you!

Comment: Which version of MySql do you run the query on? `WITH` clause is suported beginning from version 8 (still under development - this is not production/stable version). WITH clause doesn't work on 5.7 and earlier versions.